# How to retrieve Real type data from specific cell in android sqlite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

[image]

In this table, I want to retrieve the value 55.2 in a variable.
This value is at row 5 (ID=5) and in the column 'Weight' of type REAL.

I can already get the desired row number which is stored in 'lastID' and I know that my data is in the column 'Weight'. So I have my X and my Y in the table.

I also know the sqlite command to retrieve the 55.2 in my cursor:

```
Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT Weight FROM <MYTABLE> WHERE ID=" + lastID, null);
Double lastWeight = cursor2.getDouble(0);  //This line is wrong, I need the help here!
```

But I can't get the 55.2 value I am looking for in my variable lastWeight from cursor2.

Any idea?

Addendum

Here the create table:

```
String CREATE_TABLE2 = "CREATE TABLE " + <MYTABLE> + " (" + UID2 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COL_2 + " TEXT," + COL_3 + " TEXT," + COL_4 + " REAL," + COL_5 + " REAL);";
db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE2);
```

Comment: share the `CREATE TABLE` so we can tell what is the type of Weight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the execution of this line:

```
Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT Weight FROM <MYTABLE> WHERE ID=" + lastID, null);
```

you get the results in `cursor2`.
A `Cursor` instance like `cursor2` is used to loop through its rows and to do so you must first place its index at the 1st row by `moveToFirst()`:

```
if (cursor2.moveToFirst()) {
    Double lastWeight = cursor2.getDouble(0);
    ........................................
}
```

The `if` statement is necessary just in case the cursor does not contain any rows.

Comment: indeed! my code was correct but the if statement was missing to make it work properly. It's impossible to find this out if you don't know it. A great thank to you forpas!